# Xcode missing file warnings after removing Git manually

Tags: xcode, git, svn

I while ago I removed the .git folders manually from my Xcode (5) project and switched to svn. Ever since I have about 400 missing file warnings like

```
file:.../.git/objects/f2/4f16e85d07b97f2953a15b302a626806530431: warning: Missing file:
 .../4f16e85d07b97f2953a15b302a626806530431 is missing from working copy
```

Strange thing is, Xcode sees the project as a svn repository, I can view the revisions.

I think that those files are still somewhere in my project.pbxproj file.

Is there some way to remove these references automatically without destroying my svn repository?  I am afraid that disabling version control from preferences will disable subversion and not fix my problem.

It is not a huge problem, but it's kind of annoying.

Comment: Xcode is emitting those warnings if I build my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well turns out it was a svn problem. I had deleted the .git files, but they where still in the svn repository. Did an update, then an svn delete on the .git folder, recommitted.

The files where still reported missing for me in Xcode, so I created an empty .git directory, added it, deleted it with svn delete and restarted Xcode, the warnings are gone :)

Answer (score 2):

It's complaining about files in your "`.git`" folder.

Go to Terminal and "`cd`" followed by the path of the folder where your source code lives.

For example, something like:  "`cd /Users/whateveryournameis/Desktop/YourAppLivesInHere`".

Then type in "`ls -al .git`".  If you see one listed, you can remove the whole folder via "`rm -rf .git`".

Comment: These .git folders are removed already. `ls -al .git` says only that there are none. Problem is, Xcode thinks they should be there, but they are not.

Comment: Under Xcode's "Source Control" menu & submenus for your project, do you see anything that says "Configure…" (e.g. like "Configure _insert_your_repo_name_here")?

Comment: Nope, I dont see "Configure", only Checkboxes "enable source controll" and so on.